# How to split input text box value using angular

Tags: html, angularjs

i have `"<HR>*10/100"` value, how to split this value as three parts
like `"HR", "*"` and `"10/100"`

**html**

```
 <input type='text' ng-model='value' ng-change="GetAngValue(value)">
                            {{Result}}
```

**angular**

```
$scope.GetAngValue = function (value) {
    var Matches = value.match(/\<(.*?)\>/);
    if (Matches) {
        $scope.Result = Matches[1];
    }
}
```

am getting angular brackets values by using this code but how to get remaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's long way but it'll do the trick

```
value.replace("<","").replace(">",",").replace("*","*,").split(",");
```

Comment: am getting result like this["Basic","*","10/100"]  how to get that 10/100 as value .. not in double quotes is that possible

Comment: What do you mean by value? do you mean 10/100 as 0.1 you want to get?

Comment: Try eval("10/100") to get 0.1

Comment: am trying to do calculation like this var value= <10>*10/100   $scope.Matches = value.replace("<", "").replace(">", ",").replace("*", "*,").split(",");
       
        $scope.res = $scope.Matches[0] *(Math.floor($scope.Matches[2])); but it returning null  if i give only 10 it is calculating .. if i use dividend  getting null

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <input type='text' ng-model='value' ng-change="GetAngValue(value)">
                            {{Result}}
</div>

<script>
angular.module('app',[]).controller('appCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.GetAngValue = function (value) {
    var Matches = value.replace("<","").replace(">",",").replace("*","*,").split(",");
  
    if (Matches) {
        $scope.Result = Matches;
    }
  console.log(Matches);
}

})


</script>
```